# How can I Shim an extension method using Microsoft Fakes?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, microsoft-fakes, shim

I am having trouble working out how to create a Shim for an extension method.

I have an extension method in my assembly "MJH.Extensions.dll" as follows:
(obviously this isn't what the REAL method is doing .. I've simplified it for this example).

```
namespace MJH.Extensions {
  public static class ListItemExtensions {
     public static string foo(this Microsoft.SharePoint.ListItem item) {
        return string.Empty;
     }
  }
}
```

You can then of course use this easily within code ..

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using MJH.Extensions;
...
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.foo(); // returns empty string
```

I am trying to shim this method for Unit Tests ... but can't for the life of me work out how to do it.

I have added a "Fakes" assembly for my own MJH assembly, which includes the "ListItemExtensions" static class.

I've also tried adding a "Fakes" assembly for the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" assembly too.

(and all permutations of).

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using MJH.Extensions;
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MJH.Tests {

[TestClass]
public class MyTests {

   [TestMethod]
   public void TestSample() {
      using(ShimsContext()) {
        // complains that "ShimListItem.AllInstances" does not contain a definition for "foo"
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Fakes.ShimListItem.AllInstances.foo () => {
          return "something else";
        }
      }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: You need a shim for `ListItemExtensions`, not `ListItem`. An extension method is just a static method with a funky calling convention. It is not functionally part of the class it's extending.

Comment: @JeroenMostert how would I do that? The `ListItemExtensions` class is in a different namespace .. trying to do `MJH.Extensions.Fakes.ShimListItemExtensions` doesn't work

Comment: If there is no shim for it despite you configuring fakes to do so, you may need more configuration, or else the build output should contain the reason why it failed to generate the shim (you may need to up the verbosity a bit for that). It's been a while since I've used Fakes.

Comment: If it will outright refuse service on extension methods (a distinct possibility) and you still have the ability to change the code, you can trampoline the call through a non-extension method (either static or as a call on a singleton instance).